# Hyperlinks in Index pages

Tags: indexing

I have created a page on `Index`, where page numbers corresponding to index terms are shown. Now, I want to insert hyperlinks to the pages (so that navigation to those pages is easier).

Here's my MWE (it is taken from the internet):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
In this example several keywords\index{keywords} will be used 
which are important and deserve to appear in the Index\index{Index}.

Terms like generate\index{generate} and some\index{others} will 
also show up. 

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: I would suggest that you add `\usepackage{hyperref}` after (or before?) `\makeindex`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer It worked!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use `\usepackage{hyperref}`, perhaps with some options and it will automatically add the hyperlinks to the indexed pages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}%
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
In this example several keywords\index{keywords} will be used 
which are important and deserve to appear in the Index\index{Index}.

Terms like generate\index{generate} and some\index{others} will 
also show up. 

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: It used to work for me some time ago, but now (texlive 2019) it does not. Any ideas?

Comment: It works with makeidx, so I do without imakeidx.

Comment: It seems to be important to load the `imakeidx` package _before_
`hyperref`.